# Databricks pySpark datetime

Tags: datetime, pyspark, databricks

I'm not sure why my datatime is being printed the way it is. I'm expecting the format of "%Y-%M-%D" (2020-05-11)

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

currentdate = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%M-%D")
print(dateValue)

Output: 
2020-09-05/11/20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **`%Y-%m-%d`** instead of [`%Y-%M-%D`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
currentdate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")    
print (currentdate)
#2020-05-11

#or using spark sql
currentdate=spark.sql("select string(current_date)").collect()[0][0]
print(currentdate)
#2020-05-11
```

Comment: `("%Y-%m-%d")` didn't work. The output is the same.  The spark sql command worked. but would like to keep it in pySpark. Also, any idea why the pySpark output is `2020-09-05/11/20`

Comment: @jessgtrz,Not sure why it haven't worked (i have tested in python 2.7 & 3.7, it works)... from python documentation. %Y -> `year(yyyy)`,%M -> `minutes of the hour`, %m `month`, %D -> `mm/dd/yy`, %d -> `day of month`, so format `%Y-%m-%d` will gets us current date. You can use pyspark sql to get currentdate then.

Comment: might be a databricks pySpark issues? @Shu

Comment: `currentdate= spark.sql("select string(current_timestamp)").collect()[0][0]
print(currentdate)` outputs: `2020-05-11 19:24:45.476 `. How canI make my output `2020-05-11_19:24:45` @Shu

Comment: @jessgtrz, Try with `spark.sql("select string(date_format(current_timestamp,'yyyy:MM:dd_HH:mm:ss'))").collect()[0][0]` may be databricks issue but not sure..!